# Flutter Test Driver Run All Test

Tags: testing, flutter, automated-tests

In our Flutter application we have multiple [integration tests](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction).
I run them one by one by issuing:

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/screenshot.dart
```

However I can't seem to figure out how to run all `integration test` inside the `test_driver` folder?

Answer (score -1):

With Groups, but this only half addresses the issue, have your app_test.dart like normal just a main method with some grouped tests

```
Future<void> main() async {



group(
    'Registration and password',
    () {
      setUp(() async {
        await versionTest(driver, tester, reporter);
      });

      test('Register Account', () async {
        await testRegisterAccount(driver, tester, reporter);
      });

      test('Register Account 2', () async {
        await testRegisterAccount2(driver, tester, reporter);
      });

      tearDown(() async {
        await driver.requestData('go-back');
      });
    },
    timeout: const Timeout(
      Duration(minutes: 5),
    ),
  );
```

then we have an app.dart which creates the app wrapped in a test app. We mainly did this to test a splash screen that checked the apps version, so we needed a hook into before the app had really started

```
void main() {
  makeTestApp();
}
```

makeTestApp does all the normal stuff like enableFlutterDriverExtensions etc but its also where we build our app with a custom launcher, the launcher is just a blank page with a button which starts the app, each test should start and finish here, going back was harder you can see we used the FlutterDriverExtensions handler message - driver.requestData('go-back')

```
Widget _buildHome(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        child: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/authentication');
            },
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/logo.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]).then((_) {
    runApp(App(
      launcher: (context) => _buildHome(context),
    ));
  });
```

now you can start the app using something like

```
flutter run --flavor dev --observatory-port 8888 --disable-service-auth-codes --no-hot test_driver/app.dart
```

and when the app is running it will display our launcher waiting for you to run a test using the code lens tools from the dart library,

[image: codelens]

Answer (score -6):

One way to do it is to open a terminal window in the root directory of your Flutter app and type `flutter test`

See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Running-and-writing-tests#running-unit-tests

Comment: ```flutter test``` runs tests inside the `test/` directory (widget and unit). The original question is in regards to integration tests.